# Navigation Drawer closes without animation

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have created a custom navigation drawer for my app. The behavior is perfect, except that when I click one item it closes instantly, without animation. But opening and closing without selection work perfect

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends ActivityBase implements NavigationInteractions {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private TextView mToolbarTitle;
private ImageView mToolbarIcon;

private DrawerLayout drawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
private CustomDrawerAdapter drawerAdapter;
private List<DrawerItem> drawerItemList;
private ListView drawerListView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    // Handle toolbar
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbarTitle = (TextView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    mToolbarIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_icon);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    initNavigationDrawer();
    // load default fragment
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        onFragmentInteraction(NI_GOTO_SEARCH, null);
    }
}

private void initNavigationDrawer() {

    User currentUser = AccountManager.current(this);;

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    drawerItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    drawerItemList.add(new DrawerItem(DrawerItem.NAV_ITEM_TYPE_USER, currentUser.getName(), currentUser.getEmail()));
    drawerItemList.add(new DrawerItem(DrawerItem.NAV_ITEM_TYPE_BLACK_NO_ICON, "Order History"));
    drawerItemList.add(new DrawerItem(DrawerItem.NAV_ITEM_TYPE_BLACK_NO_ICON, "Log Out"));
    drawerItemList.add(new DrawerItem(DrawerItem.NAV_ITEM_TYPE_WHITE_NO_ICON, "FAQ"));
    drawerItemList.add(new DrawerItem(DrawerItem.NAV_ITEM_TYPE_WHITE_NO_ICON, "About"));
    drawerItemList.add(new DrawerItem(DrawerItem.NAV_ITEM_TYPE_WHITE_NO_ICON, "Terms & Conditions"));
    drawerItemList.add(new DrawerItem(DrawerItem.NAV_ITEM_TYPE_WHITE_NO_ICON, "Privacy Policy"));
    drawerItemList.add(new DrawerItem(DrawerItem.NAV_ITEM_TYPE_WHITE_NO_ICON, "Contact Us"));

    CustomDrawerAdapter adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_item_white_with_icon, drawerItemList);

    drawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, mToolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.syncState();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private void SelectDrawerItem(final int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            onFragmentInteraction(NI_DRAWER_GOTO_USER, null);
            break;
        case 1:
            onFragmentInteraction(NI_DRAWER_GOTO_HISTORY, null);
            break;
        case 2:
            onFragmentInteraction(NI_DRAWER_GOTO_LOGOUT, null);
            break;
    }

    drawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    drawer.closeDrawer(drawerListView, false);

}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(int interaction, Parcelable object) {

    switch (interaction) {

        case NI_GOTO_SEARCH:

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            SearchFragment.newInstance(),
                            SearchFragment.TAG)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            break;

        case NI_DRAWER_GOTO_USER:

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            ProfileFragment.newInstance(),
                            ProfileFragment.TAG)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            break;

        case NI_DRAWER_GOTO_HISTORY:

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            HistoryFragment.newInstance(),
                            HistoryFragment.TAG)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            break;

        case NI_DRAWER_GOTO_LOGOUT:

            AccountManager.logOut(this);

            startActivity(new Intent(this, OpeningActivity.class));
            finish();
            break;

        case NI_DRAWER_GOTO_FAQ:

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            ProductFragment.newInstance(),
                            ProductFragment.TAG)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            break;

        case NI_DRAWER_GOTO_ABOUT:

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            ProductFragment.newInstance(),
                            ProductFragment.TAG)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            break;

        case NI_DRAWER_GOTO_TERMS:

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            ProductFragment.newInstance(),
                            ProductFragment.TAG)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            break;

        case NI_DRAWER_GOTO_PRIVACY:

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            ProductFragment.newInstance(),
                            ProductFragment.TAG)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            break;

        case NI_DRAWER_GOTO_CONTACT:

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            ProductFragment.newInstance(),
                            ProductFragment.TAG)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(this, "No valid option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void changeActionBarTitle(String title) {

    getSupportActionBar().show();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mToolbarTitle.setText(title);
    mToolbarTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mToolbarIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void hideActionBar() {
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}

@Override
public void showActionBarAppIcon() {
    getSupportActionBar().show();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mToolbarTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mToolbarIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        SelectDrawerItem(position);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how do you close the drawer on selection?

Comment: Code. We need some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the actual line causing the freeze is:
drawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);

I just commented it while searching for an explanation

Answer (score 1):

You are having this problem because of this line :

```
drawer.closeDrawer(drawerListView, false);
```

change like that :

```
drawer.closeDrawer(drawerListView, true);
```

The boolean is for animation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the boolean for the animation to experiment, but actually it happens with true also. No difference.